# Accessing the content of the Javascript code of a web page in an extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, plugins, add-on, content-script

How we can access the content of Javascript code that is in the code of a web page in a browser extension? I want to have something like parsing the content of it in my extension.

Comment: You can use chrome.debugger API with [CDP commands](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/) like getResourceTree and getResourceContent. In the simpler case of a globally exposed function you can call its .toString() method in [page context](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9517879).

Comment: Thanks a lot, with getResourceContent, can I read the JS code of the page and decide according to its content?

Comment: Why not? Why do you ask?